# Scale Relative Layout

Tags: android, nexus-7

I need to scale Relative Layout to size of device. Relative Layout have 
 width = 2048 / height 6195.

Then in my activity I have width of device:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    Constants.sDeviceWidth= size.x;
```

Then I create Relative layout. And after it I scale my view.
1)Count scale:

```
 Float scale=(Constants.sDeviceWidth)/(float)newPage.getLayoutParams().width;
```

2) Set it:

```
 newPage.setScaleX(scale);
 newPage.setScaleY(scale);
```

3) Then I create parent view with red background for my relative layout:

```
       RelativeLayout baseLayout=new RelativeLayout(context);
       baseLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (pages.get(i).getLayoutParams().width * pages.get(i).getScaleX()), (int) (pages.get(i).getLayoutParams().height * pages.get(i).getScaleX())));
        baseLayout.addView(pages.get(i));
        baseLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

where pages.get(i) is my child view which I scaled.

Then i found problem that for Nexus 7 all is ok but for Nexus 10 child view is to small. And I don`t know why. 
Nexus 10:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEaZY.png)

Nexus 7:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEaZY.png#1)

Answer (score 0):

Am bit unclear in you question, do you want **scale Relative Layout to size of device** **or  screen** ?

If its screen, its pretty simple if you set the width of the ViewGroup to match parent.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

What are your trying to achieve here ? If this is not what yo are trying to do. Please explain.

Comment: I cant use match parent in my situation